# Scroll text within a div?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a very small div where I want to fit more text than it can fit, so I'd like to have vertical scroll-bar on the right side of it, just like the usual ones. It would be nice if I could customize looks of it.

Most of plugins I managed to find with lazy search were about scrolling animations and scrolling to a certain element of a DOM, which isn't what I want.

Comment: Are you just looking to customize your scrollbar? Here's a CSS solution I did a while ago, but only works for -webkit browsers. http://codepen.io/brbcoding/pen/xhDbd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix the height of the div, set its overflow-y to scroll. http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/pBu8q/

CSS

```
.restricted{height:150px;overflow-y:scroll}
```

HTML

```
<div class="restricted">bunch of text that will make this box scroll</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `overflow: auto` or `overflow: scroll` (`overflow-x` or `overflow-y` as appropriate) to display a scrollbar when an element’s content overflows its content box.

[Here’s a demo.](http://codepen.io/minitech/pen/gHGun)

Comment: it's in your demo, but it should be mentioned that you need to specify a height for this to work

Comment: @sgroves: You don’t, as long as the element has overflow. A negative bottom margin on child elements, absolute or fixed positioning on either the parent (two or more opposite distances [`left+right`, `top+bottom`]) or the child…

Comment: ok. take out the height in your example and try. for `overflow` to work, it needs to know at what point it should start overflowing. that requires a known height (or width for `overflow-x`).

Comment: yep. don't get what you're saying. take the `height` out of your example and see. yes, there are ways to get this to work without specifying height, but generally that's what you need to do for overflow to work.

Comment: @sgroves: I’m saying that all that’s needed is for content to overflow the element. It could be done with `height`. I think that belongs in the demo, though, since in most situations where you have a tiny box, I’d assume it already has a fixed height somehow (through positioning or setting height). Depends on the OP, though. :)

Comment: sure - you can put `overflow` on any element you want, but it won't actually DO anything unless it knows how tall/wide you want the element to be. which you can specify with `height` or `width`. your demo is correct—i was simply saying it's worth mentioning in your *answer* that you need to specify height.

Comment: @sgroves: And which you can also specify with `position` and `margin` and a lot of fun other things, but it sounded like the OP already had that down and I thought it was a bit tangential and belonged in a demo. I made it a bit clearer in an edit, though — thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Read [how to customize a scroll bar](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/)

To create scroll bar `overflow-y: scroll;` or `overflow:auto;`, you'll need to set the `width` and `height` as well

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: It was before you changed it... It was just "Read how to customize a scroll bar" with a link.

Answer (score 0):

Set the following CSS property on your div:

`overflow-y:scroll;`

Answer (score 0):

Just need CSS:

```
#element-name {
    overflow: auto; // hidden: no scrollbar, auto: shows it when needed, scroll: always show scrollbar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the following CSS styles: `height` and `width`, and `overflow-y: scroll;`, on this one. (Make sure, it is a block, `display: block;`)
Custom styles will have to wait, it's a quick-and-dirty solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of several jquery plugins for a custom scrollbar http://www.jqueryrain.com/2012/07/jquery-scrollbar-plugin-examples/